# ListBox não está adicionando SubItems

Tags: c#, listview

Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Coluna1");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1a");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1b");
item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1c");

ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Coluna2");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2a");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2b");
item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2c");

ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Coluna3");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3a");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3b");
item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3c");

listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item1,item2,item3});
```

Porém, meu listView1 está retornando apenas a seguinte informação:
Coluna1  Coluna2  Coluna3

Não aparece os dados de SubItem!
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltam algumas coisas a mais...
No construtor do ListItemView vai o nome da row, as colunas são colocadas separadamente, e tem que ativar para mostrar os subitems (View.Details).

Tente executar este código:

```
 listView1.View = View.Details;

 ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Linha1");
 item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1a");
 item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1b");
 item1.SubItems.Add("SubItem1c");

 ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Linha2");
 item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2a");
 item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2b");
 item2.SubItems.Add("SubItem2c");

 ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Linha3");
 item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3a");
 item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3b");
 item3.SubItems.Add("SubItem3c");

 listView1.Columns.Add("Coluna 1");
 listView1.Columns.Add("Coluna 2");
 listView1.Columns.Add("Coluna 3");
 listView1.Columns.Add("Coluna 4");

 listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });
```

Ah, e é uma ListView, não ListBox!

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Resolvido! 
Pois é, depois que cliquei em salvar que eu vi que tinha digitado ListBox, aí o site não deixou eu editar, rsrs!